# jQuery Stop content from jumping when overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

The default size of a scrollbar is 17px in width, however its better to let the browser calculate the exact width and then use it.

```
// Calculating the exact width of the browser scrollbar
    let scrollbarWidth=(window.innerWidth-$(window).width());
    
// then when needed to perform a click action just add this below it:
        $("body").css("overflow","hidden");
        $("body").css("padding-right", scrollbarWidth +"px");
```

Comment: What's the use-case, *why* are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `box-sizing: border-box;` in your body.

Here in this demo I set the body width to ***(100vw + 1px)*** so that it will engage the horizontal scrollbar. When you click the button, it will add the style as you showed (hiding the scrollbar and adding margin to the body).

I added borders to the button to show it correctly aligns to the right edge as intended.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($(document).width() , window.innerWidth);
    var scrollbarWidth = ($(document).width() - window.innerWidth) + "px";   

    $(document).on('click', '.is-open', function() {
      console.log(scrollbarWidth);
      if ($(this).hasClass("is-open")) {
        $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
        $("body").css("padding-right", scrollbarWidth);
      }
    });
});
```

```css
body{  
  width: calc(100vw + 2px);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px red;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;  
}

.is-open{
  cursor: pointer;  
  border: solid green;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: right;
}

.buttoncontainer{
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>Clicking the button will hide the scrollbar and add a padding-right to body</p>
  <div class="buttoncontainer">  
    <button class="is-open">Click here</button>
  </div>
</body>
```